# Why aren't all modules over fields zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, commutative-algebra, modules

I came up with the following argument which leads to a clearly false conclusion but I cannot discern where it goes wrong:

> Let $M$ be an $A$-module where $A$ is a commutative unital ring, then
> $M = 0$ if and only if $M_{\frak{m}}=0$ for every maximal ideal
> ${\frak{m}} \subseteq A$.
>
> If $A =k$ a field, then the only maximal ideal of $A$ is the
> zero-ideal $(0)$ whence $M_{(0)} = 0$ which implies that $M = 0$.
>
> Thus any module over a field is $0$.

Where does this argument fail?

Comment: Generally, $M_{(0)} \neq 0$.

Comment: What does $M_{\mathfrak{m}}$ mean?

Comment: $M_{(0)}=M$ in this case; how you show this depends on your construction of the localization of a module, but in general this is basically just the fact that $k_{(0)}=k$

Comment: Right! $M_{\frak{m}}$ is the localization of $M$ by the multiplicative set $A \setminus \frak{m}$ which in this will not contain $0$. I mixed $M_{(0)}$ up with $M_0$. Thanks!